# Is Apple allow to test Authentication Services (Apple Sign In) on Simulator

Tags: ios, applet, ios13, xcode11

I want to know that Authorization service (Apple Sign in) which apple releases recently. Does they allow to test that on simulators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I tested, they support it partially, you can perform an authorization request, go through all the sign in flow and get all the credentials with no problem. But it fails for example if you try to check user credentials, additionally every time you initiate the flow it will request your Apple ID credentials while in a device it only does the first time.

For initial tests it's ok but I'd recommend to test on an iOS device to assure everything runs fine.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference between the simulator and a real device is that the simulator will always prompt this screen:

[image]

On the other hand, on a real device this screen will be prompted only the first time and then will be displayed this screen:

[image]

Also, If you want to start testing from scratch on a real device or simulator you can go to Settings -> Apple ID -> Password & Security -> Apple ID Logins/App Using Your Apple ID -> Your app name -> Stop using Apple ID

Comment: In my case the a screen pops asks for password and go in for loading forever.